# Rstudio tries to access parent directories where I don't have access rights and crashes

Tags: rstudio

- My Project is in a shared drive //company/me/project/
- I have full read/write access to //company/me/
- I have 0 access rights in //company/

Once in a while my Rstudio crashes with the following message

```
    Unexpected exception: rstudio_boost:filesystem::status: Access is denied: "//company
```

After this i can no longer open my project via Rstudio.
The only workaround i have found is to delete .Rproj.user and create a new project in the same folder

Why is Rstudio trying to access //company/?  Is there a configuration I can set to prevent this from happening?

Edit:  I have noticed that this usually happens when theres a bug in my code or when I try to stop code that is running.

Comment: Have you sent this question to community.rstudio.com?

Comment: I didn't want to cross post initially but ive just posted it there

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason can be that Rstudio (along with R), saves your session to a `.Rdata` (either by default or possibly because you clicked "Yes" when it asked to save the `workspace` to `.Rdata`). R does this to track reproducibility of a session i.e. to determine the last state when Rstudio was closed (or crashed in your case).
And now its trying to restore an exception , which cannot be reproduced as it requires opening up the file and running it (and opening it, is what you want in the first place).

Note that as per [RStudio Documentation](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200526207-Using-Projects):  `.Rproj.user` also stores project-specific temporary files (e.g. auto-saved source documents, window-state, etc.).

- A recommended solution to this is to set option for never saving the session data i.e. every time Rstudio starts , it is starting with a clean slate for your project. If you are concerned about loosing the commands you ran in your last session , set the option of `Always Save History (Even when not saving .RData)`. See the image below to set things as a default (sourced from [Hadley's Comment](https://community.rstudio.com/t/first-line-of-every-r-script/799/12)):

[image: Hadley's Reply]

The same settings are also present for a Project too:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for this.  But the question is why RStudio needs to access upper level directories.  If Rstudio only saves to the local folder, there should not be problems.

Comment: If you are accessing the project via RStudio Server, access conflict can probably occur due to another file called `.rstudio` which saves `session` data at `/home` location for a user (the os level user created for you). This location must be outside your `//company/me/` folder and hence the permission error trying to access session from `//company` folder, you can ask your admin to make `//company/me/`  as the default `/home` folder for your user.